# Converted SOSL from SOQL is not working

Tags: soql, developer-console, sosl

SOQL query

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity
    WHERE College__r.Phone LIKE '%7411162213'
        OR College__r.OtherPhone LIKE '%7411162213'
```

on running on developer console it gives result total rows fetched 1

I want its equivalent SOSL query. I converted to following:

```
FIND {7411162213} IN ALL FIELDS
    RETURNING Opportunity(Id, Name WHERE College__r.Phone LIKE '%7411162213'
                                       OR College__r.OtherPhone LIKE '%7411162213')
```

but this does not give me any result on developer console. Total rows fetched is 0.

Am I missing anything in above SOSL query?

Comment: You have SOSL and SOQL the wrong way round. You need to [wildcard the FIND value](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337766&type=1&mode=1).

Comment: I don't think relationships are supported in SOSL or a WHERE clause.

Comment: I think he wants `FIND {7411162213} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Opportunity(Id, Name, CollegePhoneCalc__c, OtherPhoneCalc__c )`

Comment: @CasparHarmer indeed. As per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm) this must be "The name of a field for the specified object".

Comment: Except I think I'm wrong about the WHERE clause... of course this query doesn't actually NEED a WHERE clause

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so assuming you are actually after `SOSL`:

First, you can't have relationship fields. So replace them with calculated fields.
(Ie, `College__r.OtherPhone` becomes `CollegeOtherPhone__c`

Secondly, you don't need the `WHERE` clause - you are already searching by the same value in the find part. If you DID want to filter a bit more, you'd do that in the `WHERE` clause, but you'd be excluding records based on different criteria.

Which leaves you with something like this:

```
FIND {7411162213} IN ALL FIELDS 
RETURNING Opportunity(Id, Name, CollegePhoneCalc__c, OtherPhoneCalc__c )
```

Comment: thanks. understood that where clause is not needed.

Comment: but still needs to figure out how to use relationships

Comment: FIND {7411162213} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Opportunity(Id, Name, CollegePhone__c, CollegeOtherPhone__c )



RETURNING Opportunity(Id, Name, CollegePhone__c, CollegeOtherPhone__c
                                ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:65
No such column 'CollegePhone__c' on entity 'Opportunity'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Oh, you have to go and make that field. You would create it as a formula field on Opportunity? and it's just equal to `College__r.OtherPhone` for example

Comment: ok . can relationships not be used like sosl? FIND {9122065057*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Opportunity(Id, Name, College__r.OtherPhone, College__r.Phone)

Comment: That's correct. You cannot use relationship fields in SOSL. You can in SOQL.  SOQL is like `SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '006232323234'`. You want SOSL. SOQL => SOSL.

Comment: @gouravkumar Have a look at this question, which may have a way to work around it: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213425/performing-a-relationship-query-in-a-sosl-query